# when call back in media player and again call in android

Tags: android

I am creating one media player apps in that i have two activities Home and Display, Home having with list of songs , when i select particular song from Home it will redirect to Display activity, now the problem is when i back pressed it will redirect to Home activity and media player is still working and playing that song but when i select same song on Home activity it will create another object of media player class and run another same song, i want to save currently running song state what should i do??

Comment: If you want to stop the previous media, you can override onStop() function and stop it there

Comment: Thanks Omar but , i got solution just store your Media Player Object in another class using public static List<MediaPlayer> mList = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>(); and checked it if its playing or not..